# Hardhat multiple folders for compilation

Tags: solidity, hardhat

Is there a way to provide multiple folders for compilation in hardhat config? I test my contracts with the foundry and all test contracts are under test/foundry folder so the written code in this folder is not validated because they are not part of hardhat project. So to check the contract for any mistakes I have to compile it manually.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `sources` directory is where your contract are stored, and Hardhat compiles all contracts in the contracts directory at any nesting level. The `tests` directory is where your tests are located. If you want to test your contracts, your testing files should be under the `tests` directory.

See: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config

Comment: The test directory in hardhat basically contains js or ts files with tests. I've mentioned in my question that I use the foundry library together with my hardhat project. With foundry, I am able to write tests in solidity language and to make foundry work I have to put all test contracts into test/foundry directory. The problem is that hardhat doesn't validate and compile solidity files which are not in the contracts directory, so that's why I need to have kind of array of source pathes. @Yongjian P.

Comment: I don' think the paths object allows for array fields yet in hardhat.config. See: https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/776

Comment: Yeah, looks like. Bc I haven't found a way to overcome it

Comment: You're correct in that the documentation says "at any nesting level."   Unfortunately, the documentation is wrong.  If you have a directory that's a simlink, only contracts in the top level are compiled.